# Signed FatJar is really slow at runtime

Tags: java, jar, jarsigner, jar-signing

I have a rather large signed FatJar (~150Mb) and I just tried running it and it turns out that it runs much slower than its unsigned equivalent. I'm using jdk1.8.0_131 (on Mac).

I'm curious as to whether this is normal or whether there are some tips and tricks that I can use to speed things up.

I noticed that the signing process actually signs each individual entry in the jar as opposed to signing the Jar as a whole. So I imagine that the slowness is due to the class loader having to verify the signature of every class it tries to load.

So my question is, is there a way to change this behavior? Can I have the class loader somehow just verify that the JAR is properly signed to begin with and then behave the same as if it were an unsigned JAR?

If not, I will implement my own signing/verification mechanism. Just want to make sure I'm not missing anything before I do that.

Comment: Which Java version are you running the jar on?

Comment: Just updated the question with that information. jdk1.8.0_131 on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a java bug.

See [here](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6354728)

Actually sign verification should not has a significant impact on overall performance.

So try to update JDK version.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't look like this is the case for me. We're using JDK 1.8 (jdk1.8.0_131). I'll update my question to make note of that.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of slowness in calling a REST API, requests took up to 4 seconds instead of less than a second.

The reason was that
creating a client takes a lot of time.
Basically the solution was to make the client creation a singleton, then it was fast again.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: Well in the experience i shared it shows that when creating external connections with a signed jar the run gets slower at runtime.. its a potential reason.. could be something else.. and the solution to this is creating 1 external connection in a singleton then using it instead of creating multiple connections at runtime or in a loop

Comment: @StinkyPointer might be on to something. I have a Java utility built as a FatJar that makes dozens of thousands sequential REST API calls per session. Unsigned version finishes the session under 3 minutes. When the JAR is signed - the same session runs over 30 minutes. I'm still investigating what causes it...